# In laravel now datetime showing wrong

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Inside a laravel project,php's `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` function is printing 6 hours minus `time()` and `Carbon::now()` is also printing the same.

Can anyone tell me, how can i print my current time?

In my laravel project's `config/app.php` I have set `'timezone' => 'UTC'`.

Comment: Is "your current time" UTC, e.g., are you in London? If it is 6 hours before when you expect you are likely around India.

Comment: i'm in Bangladesh and my timezone is "Asia/Dhaka"

Comment: @sh6210 so set it in config file if you're using just one timezone in your app. Or pass it to `now()`

Answer (score 4):

You can try to add timezone. Example from [Carbon docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/):

```
Carbon::now('Europe/London');
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify "your" timezone:

In `config/app.php` write:

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Dhaka'
```